# XSLT 2.0/3.0- Selecting two records and inserting missing entries

Tags: xslt

I am working on a tricky requirement. I have some xml data which contains the holiday/weekend information. I need to insert missing dates in between (assuming missing days are working days).

I am thinking to get the first date and last date and then run a loop for number of days in that month and then insert the missing days but that requires finding the month information, and there may be all the months in the data.

Is there any quicker way to manipulate the dates in XSLT.

```
<HOLIDAYS>
        <item>
            <DATE>2020-01-01</DATE>
            <FREEDAY>X</FREEDAY>
            <HOLIDAY/>
            <HOLIDAY_ID/>
            <TXT_SHORT/>
            <TXT_LONG/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <DATE>2020-01-11</DATE>
            <FREEDAY>X</FREEDAY>
            <HOLIDAY/>
            <HOLIDAY_ID/>
            <TXT_SHORT/>
            <TXT_LONG/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <DATE>2020-01-12</DATE>
            <FREEDAY>X</FREEDAY>
            <HOLIDAY/>
            <HOLIDAY_ID/>
            <TXT_SHORT/>
            <TXT_LONG/>
        </item> 
        <item>
            <DATE>2020-01-18</DATE>
            <FREEDAY>X</FREEDAY>
            <HOLIDAY/>
            <HOLIDAY_ID/>
            <TXT_SHORT/>
            <TXT_LONG/>
        </item>
</HOLIDAYS>

output required

<HOLIDAYS>
    <item>
        <DATE>2020-01-01</DATE>
        <FREEDAY/>
        <HOLIDAY/>
        <HOLIDAY_ID/>
        <TXT_SHORT/>
        <TXT_LONG/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <item>
            <DATE>2020-01-02</DATE>
            <FREEDAY/>
            <HOLIDAY/>
            <HOLIDAY_ID/>
            <TXT_SHORT/>
            <TXT_LONG/>
        </item>
        <DATE>2020-01-03</DATE>
        <FREEDAY>X</FREEDAY>
        <HOLIDAY/>
        <HOLIDAY_ID/>
        <TXT_SHORT/>
        <TXT_LONG/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <DATE>2020-01-04</DATE>
        <FREEDAY>X</FREEDAY>
        <HOLIDAY/>
        <HOLIDAY_ID/>
        <TXT_SHORT/>
        <TXT_LONG/>
    </item> 
        
.....       
        
        <item>
        <DATE>2020-01-31</DATE>
        <FREEDAY>X</FREEDAY>
        <HOLIDAY/>
        <HOLIDAY_ID/>
        <TXT_SHORT/>
        <TXT_LONG/>
    </item>
</HOLIDAYS>
```

Comment: It might help us to understand your requirement if you show the result you want. There is some date manipulation support in XPath/XSLT 2 and later, using the `xs:date` datatype, the `xs:duration` datatypes and the operations to add or substract durations to dates.

Comment: I added the output required as 'output required', basically I want to add all the days between the missing dates..

Comment: If the last date in the XML input sample is `<DATE>2020-01-18</DATE>`, why does the output have days after that date if the task is to add the days between the existing dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment, you can substract `xs:date`s to get a duration, convert it to "a day" using division by a duration of a single day, then you should have the number of times you want to insert a new date:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="item[following-sibling::item]">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="(1 to xs:integer((following-sibling::item[1]/DATE/xs:date(.) - xs:date(DATE)) div xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')) - 1) ! current()" mode="empty"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="item" mode="empty">
      <xsl:copy>
          <DATE>{xs:date(DATE) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D') * position()}</DATE>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That only inserts the `item`s with new `DATE`s, you can `xsl:copy-of select="* except DATE"` the other elements if needed or insert any new content.